# C# Xamarin SQLite Database Error

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I still getting the same error on every device I have while using SQLite:
"System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so occurred"

It always happens on this line:

```
var r = SQLite3.Open (databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int) openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
```

What can I do?

EDIT: Is this function correct used???:

```
public bool CreateDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "CryptoSimulator.db")))
        {
            connection.CreateTable<Portfolio>();
            connection.CreateTable<Wallet>();
            connection.CreateTable<Assignments>();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did have a same problem try to downgrade your Xamarin if you are on Windows but mac seems to be stable

Comment: you mean android 7.0?

Comment: I am now running 7.1.1